# React Router v5 matching error when adding routes via a sub-component

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, ionic5

I have an Ionic React app and I'm seeing some strange behavior from my router when I use a  sub-component that provides some routes with a 404 component that matches all routes.

[The Ionic IonReactRouter component is a wrapper for React Router's BrowserRouter component.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation#ionreactrouter)

**App.tsx**

```
<IonReactRouter>
  <IonTabs>
    <IonRouterOutlet>
      <Route path={routeContactUs}>
        <ContactUs />
      </Route>
      <RoutesAppSetup />
      <Route>
        <Error404 />
      </Route>
    </IonRouterOutlet>
 </IonTabs>
</IonReactRouter>
```

**RoutesAppSetup.tsx**

```
const RoutesAppSetup: React.VFC = () => (
  <>
    <Route exact path={routeSetupVerifyEmail}>
      <AppSetupVerifyEmail />
    </Route>
  </>
```

**Problem**

When I navigate to `routeSetupVerifyEmail`, I see the `Error404` component, not `AppSetupVerifyEmail` component.  However, if I delete the `<Route><Error404 /></Route>`, then I **do** see the `AppSetupVerifyEmail` component.

How do I get it to return the component that matches the route (`AppSetupVerifyEmail`) instead of the component that matches all routes (`Error404`)?

If I add the `AppSetupVerifyEmail` component without embedding it within another component, the route resolves correctly:

**App.tsx**

```
<IonReactRouter>
  <IonTabs>
    <IonRouterOutlet>
      <Route path={routeContactUs}>
        <ContactUs />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path={routeSetupVerifyEmail}>
        <AppSetupVerifyEmail />
      </Route>
      <Route>
        <Error404 />
      </Route>
    </IonRouterOutlet>
 </IonTabs>
</IonReactRouter>
```

However, I want to use the route in a sub-component (`RoutesAppSetup`) because I have to use this same set of routes in multiple routers in my app and I don't want to duplicate the code.  How can I do that?

Comment: OK, thought the removal of the fragments would possibly work. Is there a way to create a running demo that reproduces this issue that we could live debug in?

Comment: Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-water-iqtdt?file=/src/App.tsx